# Wrong top statement declaration in Scala for main method in object

Tags: scala, error-handling

I am getting an error saying " Wrong top declaration " and " Declaration never used", I have been learning Scala for almost 11 days but I never got this error but it is getting an error now

```
object Day12
    {
      def main(args: Array[String]):Unit=>
        {
          println("Hello World!")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it comes from this piece of code and not something else? If you replaced `Unit=>` with `Unit =` it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you got, is because the definition of your method is wrong. The artcile [scala methods](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/taste-methods.html) shows how to define them.

> ##### Scala methods
>
> Scala classes, case classes, traits, enums, and objects can all contain methods. The syntax of a simple method looks like this:
>
> ```scala
> def methodName(param1: Type1, param2: Type2): ReturnType =
>   // the method body
>   // goes here
> ```

In your case, you have a `=>` instead of `=`. Just changing that, should fix the compilation error

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]):Unit = {
  println("Hello World!")
}
```